# Upgrade RHEL server kernel’s from 7.7 to 7.9

Tags: azure, linux-kernel, kernel, rhel

We are trying to upgrade RHEL server kernel’s from 7.7 to 7.9.

yum check-update is throwing below error :

Update notice RHBA-2015:0705 (from rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-optional-rpms) is broken, or a bad duplicate, skipping.

You should report this problem to the owner of the rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms repository

I am new to RHEL VMs in Azure so appreciate any help with this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested creating a Linux (redhat 7.7) and then following MS [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-2017) and then ran `sudo yum check-update` it didn't provide me any errors . this is the url i did curl to `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo`

Comment: Thank you . Do i need to have subscription to the RHUI to update the kernal ? I only have below listed subscriptions and RHUI is not there and its the only repo which is failing while check update .

Comment: 13560/13560
Update notice RHSA-2014:0678 (from rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-optional-rpms) is broken, or a bad duplicate, skipping.
You should report this problem to the owner of the rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-optional-rpms repository.
If you are the owner, consider re-running the same command with --verbose to see the exact data that caused the conflict.
Update notice RHEA-2015:0476 (from rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-optional-rpms) is broken, or a bad duplicate, skipping.

Comment: yes , I believe you need to have a license as RHUI is a licensing server for RHEL..

Comment: May i know what image of RHEL you are using in that VM and what is the type of subscription you have ?

Comment: `yum update kernel`?